# CarRacing-v0 in Gym: The screen is totally black when I run the environment

Tags: opencv, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, openai-api

I'm trying to run one of the gym environments, CarRacing, with the code from (https://gist.github.com/lmclupr/b35c89b2f8f81b443166e88b787b03ab) modified to work with the current versions of Keras etc.

And it works: that is, it starts training and, if I put a print in "action", I can see what actions it is taking at each moment.

However, the display is not as it should be (see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pTYOyl8To7g), but I get a big screen that is totally black, and a smaller one where the black bar moves as if it wanted to show something.

Do you know what it could be? Is this a typical problem of gym, or cv...?

PS: I don't know how it is usually done in Stack to share a more or less long code (approx. 250 lines). Tell me if necessary.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

See link below
TDLR add `env.render("human")` to your code

https://github.com/openai/gym/issues/492